# Do any prevalent Javascript frameworks provide a utility for pruning objects?

Tags: javascript, object

We're using jQuery on a less UI-intensive project whereas we have been using ExtJS on other projects.  Regardless, I'm curious if any of the prevalent libraries such as ExtJS, jQuery, or others, provide a utility for "pruning" objects?  By which I mean, deleting keys if they don't contain values.

I've devised my own (naive) implementation as follows, so its no biggie.  Still though just curious as I believe this could be generally useful.  I've googled for "jquery prune object" but no results seem worth investigating though of course I could be wrong ;)

```
function pruneObj(obj) {
    var empty = [];
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (!obj[attr]) {
            empty.push(attr); //rather than trying to delete the element in place
        }
    }
    for (var i=0, n=empty.length; i<n; i++) {
        delete(obj[empty[i]]);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

```
var obj = { hasFoo: false, count: 0 }
```

would (after a call to `prunObj(obj)`) be just `{}`?

I don't think any library out there would make the assumption of what values to deem "empty". It's too destructive/mutative a function to include as part of a standard set of utility functions.

Many libraries or browsers include a facility to filter out items from arrays that don't meet a certain criteria. Eg [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
list.filter(function(item){
    return !item.foo
})
```

will filter out items in `list` that have a ["falsey" value](http://www.protonfish.com/jslang.shtml) in the `foo` property.

**Edit**:

On further thought, `undefined` seems to be considered "empty" by both jQuery and [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). jQuery's `extend` function can do what I think you're aiming for with `undefined`, albeit with a slightly different syntax and *without* mutating the passed argument:

```
A = { hasFoo: false, count: 0, foo: null, bar: undefined };
B = jQuery.extend({}, A); // B = { hasFoo: false, count: 0, foo: null }
```

Swap `"jQuery"` with `"Object"` for the Prototype equivalent.

Comment: You are correct, obj above would be just {} after using my pruneObj function.  This is precisely why I said my implementation was naive ;)  Thanks for reminding me about the various libraries' filtering functions.  However do they filter objects as opposed to lists as you indicate?  Anyway it gives me a better starting point for research, so thanks!